# perl regex through command line

Tags: regex, perl

I made a little script to rename the value "S076852" into "S076852D" in all the files of a directory. Though, I don't know why it proprely switches the value but add more character.

Before running the programm:

```
./MEMOD39:%include '~S076852/PROCL/MCEV/MODELA39';
```

After running the program:

```
./MEMOD39:%include '~S076852DDDDD/PROCL/MCEV/MODELA39';
```

Any body gets why it keeps adding more "D" ?

(running on AIX)

```
url=/adirectory/
filei=`ls $url`
for file in ${filei}; do
  find ${url} -type f |  xargs perl -pi -e 's/S076852/S076852D/g'
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop isn't doing anything useful.  You aren't actually using the filenames in filei, just repeating your find/substitute unnecessarily.

Just use

`find /adirectory/ -type f | xargs perl -pi -e 's/S076852/S076852D/g'`

Answer (score 1):

You add the `D` after `S076852` every time. So you make sure thet there is no `D` after the number:

```
url=/adirectory/
filei=`ls $url`
for file in ${filei}; do
  find ${url} -type f |  xargs perl -pi -e 's/S076852\//S076852D\//g'
done
```